# Content of list change unexpected in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building one example to create all the subsets of one list:
My code is like follow, I have copy result value to another temp list and manipulate in the temp list, but don't know why in step 1 and step 3 the 'result' I print is different. I haven't make any change yet.

```
a=[1,2,3]

result=[]
temp=[]


def sub_sets(i,result):
    print("1start result:",result)
    temp=result[:]
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        temp[j].append(i)
    temp.append([i])
    print("2temp:",temp)
    print("3 middle result:",result)
    result.extend(temp)
    print("4end result:",result)


for i in range(len(a)):
    sub_sets(a[i],result)

Results:
1start result: []
2temp: [[1]]
3 middle result: []
4end result: [[1]]
1start result: [[1]]
2temp: [[1, 2], [2]]
3 middle result: [[1, 2]]
4end result: [[1, 2], [1, 2], [2]]
1start result: [[1, 2], [1, 2], [2]]
2temp: [[1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3], [3]]
3 middle result: [[1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3]]
4end result: [[1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3],  [2, 3], [3]]
```

Comment: Keeping global variables (temp and result here) as argument of a function will lead to special treatment. I would not recommend this for beginners. Best to keep rename global variables to some other names.

Comment: Don't use `... in range(len(x))` when you can just use `... in x`. If you need the index as well use `for index, value in enumerate(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Result and temp (arguments of the function) are global variables which leads to their special treatment. Following code does not have this problem:

```
a=[1,2,3]
def sub_sets(i,result):
    print("1start result:",result)
    temp=result[:]
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        temp[j].append(i)
    temp.append([i])
    print("2temp:",temp)
    print("3 middle result:",result)
    result.extend(temp)
    print("4end result:",result)

for i in range(len(a)):
    result1=[]
    sub_sets(a[i],result1)
```

Output:

```
1start result: []
2temp: [[1]]
3 middle result: []
4end result: [[1]]
1start result: []
2temp: [[2]]
3 middle result: []
4end result: [[2]]
1start result: []
2temp: [[3]]
3 middle result: []
4end result: [[3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've changed `result` because after the first time sub_sets is called, `result` and `temp` both contain a copy of the same list. You add the list `[i]` to `temp` and then add the same list to `result` when you call `result.extend(temp)`.

Comment: Hi Nathan, yes, the first time I call the sub_sets, it's change as expected, but when I call the second time, you can see when the sub_set start the result list is '1start result: [[1]]' but after I change the temp the result has been change to '3 middle result: [[1, 2]]', but during these period I still have not called result.extend.

Comment: That's true, but you have called `temp[0].append(2)` (in the for loop inside `sub_sets`), and at that point `temp[0]` is _the same list_ as `result[0]`, so `result` changes too.